# Make this dynamic with a for in

Tags: javascript

I use a router script called "Routie" that works so:

```
routie = ({
   "": function(){
      //code after routing
   },
   "home": function(){
      //code after routing
   },
   "about": function(){
      //code after routing
   }
});
```

After, I have a json file,

```
{
    "links" : [
        {"page" : "Home", "url" : "home", "file" : "template_1.html"},
        {"page" : "About", "url" : "about", "file" : "template_2.html"},
        {"page" : "Contact", "url" : "contact", "file" : "template_3.html"},
        {"page" : "Categories", "url" : "categories", "file" : "template_4.html"}
    ]
}
```

that extract through this code

```
readTextFile("menu.json", function(text){
  var data = JSON.parse(text);
}
```

I will pass my routes according to my json file, making a dinamycally object with the info of the route:

```
readTextFile("menu.json", function(text){
   var data = JSON.parse(text);
   for(item in data["links"]){
   var key = data["links"][item]["url"];
   var file = data["links"][item]["file"];
   array_rooter[key] = function(){ 
      loader(file,'content'); 
   };
   routie(array_router);
}
```

But it doesn't work :/

Anyone know what are I doing wrong?

Comment: [Don't use `for…in` enumerations on arrays!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)

Comment: But json has an object structure, not?

Comment: `links` has an array structure. (Sure arrays are objects in js, and that's why it did work for now, but you still should use proper iteration for the reasons explained in the linked post).